# control jenkins external logging?

Tags: tomcat, logging, jenkins, tomcat7, jenkins-plugins

I'm running the latest version of Jenkins (1.584) under Tomcat 7.0.56 on OS X 10.10.  We have a number of plugins installed.  I'm seeing an XML log file (java0.log) written to the home directory of the user under which Tomcat runs.  A sample record:

```
<record>
  <date>2014-10-20T09:42:19</date>
  <millis>1413816139820</millis>
  <sequence>4283</sequence>
  <logger>svnkit-cli</logger>
  <level>INFO</level>
  <class>org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.DefaultSVNDebugLogger</class>
  <method>log</method>
  <thread>56</thread>
  <message>CLI: executing statement: CREATE TRIGGER nodes_delete_trigger AFTER DELETE ON nodes WHEN OLD.checksum IS NOT NULL BEGIN UPDATE pristine SET refcount = refcount - 1 WHERE checksum = OLD.checksum; END;</message>
</record>
```

It isn't just svnkit that's logging errors.  I also see the following values in the  field:

```
javax.jmdns.impl.DNSIncoming
javax.jmdns.impl.DNSIncoming$MessageInputStream
javax.jmdns.impl.constants.DNSRecordType
javax.jmdns.impl.constants.DNSRecordClass
hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger
hudson.scm.SubversionSCM
hudson.plugins.jira.JiraChangeLogAnnotator
hudson.model.UpdateSite
jenkins.model.lazy.LazyBuildMixIn
```

What I'd like to know is how to specify a location for this log file (instead of just ~/java0.log) and how to control the log level so that only "ERROR" and above are logged.

What logger is being used here, and what java property would I need to set in order to modify its behavior?  Is this something I'd need to set Tomcat-wide (e.g. in bin/setenv.sh) or something that can be specified for only the Jenkins webapp?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat's logging properties are contained within `${catalina.base}/conf/logging.properties`. These properties apply to Tomcat and any apps contained within Tomcat, unless a specific logging solution is configured within the app. Per Hudson/Jenkins, "System log captures output from java.util.logging output related to Hudson."  Based on that, it seems the java.util.logging.consoleHandler is the one you want to modify.

In some cases where log4j is in use, the logging properties will be in a file called log4j.xml, but the format is similar and as easy to understand.

Here's the default logging.properties file, for reference:

```
############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

Comment: I think this may be something else.  The java0.log file is appearing in the build user's home directory and not in ${catalina.base}.

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about it, it looks like it could be related to SVN, based on the text in the log file.  If your Jenkins instance is invoking SVN commands, those are occurring in the shell, not in Jenkins.  I'd look to your SVN config for more information.